# simplify if statement in several AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I need to use the same `if..else` to deal with every AJAX data in my code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/aall.json",
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: "data",
    cache: false,
    ifModified: true,
    success: function getData(data){
        console.log(data);    
        for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
            // if...else
        }
    });
```

There are several AJAX get differnt:

```
$.ajax({...});
$.ajax({...});
$.ajax({...});
$.ajax({...});
```

if...else code:

```
            if(MainClass_Code=="PD" || MainClass_Code=="CD"){
                newsKindRepalce = "aipl";//news
            }else if(MainClass_Code=="PF" || MainClass_Code=="JF"){
                newsKindRepalce = "aopl";//international
            }else if(MainClass_Code=="CU"){
                newsKindRepalce = "acul";//culture
            }else{
                newsKindRepalce = "acn";//artist 
            }
```

It's would be very heavy when I use `if...else` in my all AJAX to deal with data, how can I do to simplify this?

Comment: Use functions? You also don’t need `if` and `else`. Define a `const mapping = { "PD": "aipl", "CD": "aipl", "PF": "aopl",` … `};`, then just assign `newsKindRepalce = mapping[MainClass_Code] || "acn";`.

Comment: @Xufox Why not post an answer? This looks like a good approach.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Well, it was just a suggestion. This likely still won’t fully solve the problem. The question feels a bit too vague for me to answer.

Answer (score 1):

change your `if else` to this:

```
const code = { PD: "aipl", CD: "aipl", PF: "aopl", JF: "aopl", CU: "acul" };

newsKindRepalce = code.hasOwnProperty(MainClass_Code)
  ? code[MainClass_Code]
  : "acn";
```